# SQL Server procedure throwing a parameter error even though I entered a value

Tags: sql-server, file, stored-procedures, parameters

I am doing a procedure that accepts an input parameter of a filepath, reads the json data from it and inserts the data into a table. However, when I try to execute the procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure main.loadData, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 244]
>   Procedure or function 'loadData' expects parameter '@filePath', which was not supplied.

The surprising thing is that I am adding a parameter..

The code for the procedure is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE main.loadData
    (@filePath VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pathScript AS VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @pathScript='DECLARE @jsonVariable NVARCHAR(max);
                     SELECT @jsonVariable = BulkColumn
                     FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @filepath     
                                      + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;

    INSERT INTO main.jsonData(restaurant, priceRange, country, score, reviewDate)
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVariable, ''$.reviews.row'')
        WITH
            (restaurant VARCHAR(100) ''$.restaurant'',
             priceRange VARCHAR(50) ''$.priceRange'',
             country VARCHAR(50) ''$.country'',
             score INTEGER ''$.score'',
             reviewDate DATETIME ''$.reviewDate''
            );';

    EXEC(@pathScript);
END;
GO
```

And the execution code is this:

```
EXEC main.loadData 'C:\data.json';
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @AdnanSharif Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: try EXEC main.loadData @filePath = 'C:\data.json';

Comment: @Brad Same error.

Comment: @jms15 I don't know which situation are you facing. But the above format seems to be okay. here is the [working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fbc05a5baf9868568d34e2ed6dd1c41).

Comment: It doesn't seem like the error message you would get but you are using different capitalizations for @filePath/@filepath in the procedure.

Comment: @Crowcoder I noticed that earlier and fixed it, however, it did not make a difference as it is giving me the same error

Comment: your code is seems to correct. Problem in some different aspect.  first you remove entire procedure logic and keep parameter only and execute the procedure. If it works then slowly slowly add your logic and do trial and error. In this way you  identify your root cause like from where you got the error.

Comment: If you were actually doing what your question described, your code would work.  You have to be doing something different.  Can you post a script that fully reproduces the error?

Comment: @TabAlleman I am running the procedure that I posted above, which before was the same, just without a parameter, and then I run the execute line with the path parameter and gives me that error..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a parameter in the declaration.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE main.loadData
    @filePath VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pathScript AS VARCHAR(MAX), @params VARCHAR(200);

    SET @params = @filepath VARCHAR(200);

    SET @pathScript='DECLARE @jsonVariable NVARCHAR(max);
                     SELECT @jsonVariable = BulkColumn
                     FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @params   
                                      + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;

    INSERT INTO main.jsonData(restaurant, priceRange, country, score, reviewDate)
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVariable, ''$.reviews.row'')
        WITH
            (restaurant VARCHAR(100) ''$.restaurant'',
             priceRange VARCHAR(50) ''$.priceRange'',
             country VARCHAR(50) ''$.country'',
             score INTEGER ''$.score'',
             reviewDate DATETIME ''$.reviewDate''
            );';

    EXEC(@pathScript);
END;
GO
```

And try executing like this

```
EXEC main.loadData @filepath = 'C:\data.json'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that and it gave me this error:

Cannot bulk load. The file "@filepath VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

Comment: I made an edit. My assumption for what's going wrong is; either setting the `@filepath` variable in the beginning needs to be set to `NOT NULL` or placeholder value, or `@pathScript` looking for `@filepath` but no declaration in between is linking the original path you are passing.

Comment: try changing the file location and see if you are getting the same error message.

Comment: @FaisalMehboob I tried changing the location, thought it didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. And it's the silliest problem.. Part of my program has a trigger which fires after this procedure inserts the data into the table. Now, to avoid inserting multiple times on the same table (meaning if u execute 2 times, you get double the data), i added a DELETE FROM main.jsonData, and then EXEC main.loadData (which at time didn't need any parameters). Due to this execution line, which didnt give the parameter, it gave me the error. Thanks to everyone that helped!